# How to synchronize multiple animations in different views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I'm working on an iPhone application that uses pulsating buttons and displays a clock.. so I need to synchronize the pulsating buttons with one another and with the clock display..

I'm no Core Animation expert, but so far the only synchronization mechanisms I have found work between CALayers of the same view. Am I missing something or is there really no way of synchronizing animations between views and with external events?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

BTW the app is specifically developed for iOS 5 should that make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just answered something very similar recently. You'll need to use the`CAMediaTiming`protocol. For more details and links to Apple's great video on this subject see my answer to this post:

[If statement on NSNotificationCenter in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925952/if-statement-on-nsnotificationcenter-in-ios/7957072#7957072)